Azure synapse trigger from event file creation, how to get user creation
How to get the user that created a file in a blob storage, from the trigger that is being triggered from the file creation in azure synapse analytics.
I can get for instance the file name:
@triggerBody().fileName
But I don't know how to get the user that has created the file
How to get the user that created a file in a blob storage, from the trigger that is being triggered from the file creation in azure synapse analytics.


How to get the user that created a file in a blob storage, from the trigger that is being triggered from the file creation in azure synapse analytics.

AFAIK, Azure Synapse Analytics does not have inbuilt feature to capture the user information who created a file in Azure Blob Storage through Synapse triggers.
The work around you can try is by using Azure Synapse Analytics Activity log tab to see who initiated the pipeline Run.

If you want more detailed information use Azure Synapse Analytics diagnostic logging where you can get the logs of all pipelines and query them to get the required information.
